# How do I make a 3D plot using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have to make a 3D plot of the function `y = sin(2*pi*x)` and `y=cos(2*pi*x)` using 500 evenly spaced values. The tutorials I've been reading always include an extra `z` variable, so I'm confused how I would implement this.

I tried something I got from another tutorial:

```
t = 0 : pi/500 : pi;
st = sin(2*pi*t);
ct = cos(2*pi*t);

figure
plot3(st,ct,t)
```

I get this output:

[image]

But it's not like the mesh 3D output I was expecting. What is the right way to do this?

Here's something that I expected. I expect this output because in a previous assignment I was told to make a 3D plot of `x^a*y^b` and it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a function z = f(x,y)? What's the function? You define two different functions y = f(x)

Comment: @LuisMendo The assignment just says "Create a 3D plot of `y = sin(2πx), y = cos(2πx)` over `[0,π]`, using 500 evenly spaced values." What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Hm that doesn't make sense to me, sorry. Those are just two 2D plots

Comment: @LuisMendo So is the person who made the assignment wrong? If so, how would I make a 2d plot of that?

Comment: @templateboy Do you have an image of what you expect?

Comment: @Suever Please see the edit. That's the output I got before when a previous assignment said to make a 3D plot of `x^a y^b` for `a` and `b` in `[0, 2*Pi]`.

Comment: @LuisMendo Now my professor says use `z = cos(2 pi*x)`, instead of `y = cos(2 pi*x)`. Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make a 3D plot is just having three variables. The problem you are posting is wrong for me, what you can do is to plot both equations in the same figure by using the "hold on" function.

Comment: Now my professor says use `z = cos(2 pi*x)`, instead of `y = cos(2 pi*x)`. Does that help at all?